# Cant add a list of inventory items to my character in a basic c# program

Tags: c#, .net

Total rookie question i know. But i cant figure it out. I have created all the individual parts but cant bring them together.
Im building a simple c# program. I have a main, character and item class.

When we start a list of available items is created from the Item class called availableItems.

A character is made.
Now i want to give the character an inventory of those same 'availableItems'.
Yet i cant get it right. I thought it would be as simple as adding a empty list to the contructor.
Then i tried having a public method that would create a list called currentInvintory. but it was nothing but red line errors.
Im not sure what to do so i just took the code back to a working state and put out the call for help.
How do i give this little man an invintory!?

Thanks for helping a budding c sharper

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ClassMaster // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    public class Item : IEquatable<Item>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Effect {  get; set; }

        public Item(int id, string name, int effect) { 
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Effect = effect;
        }

        public void PrintItem()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invintory Item Id: " + Id + " Name: " + Name);
        }

        public bool Equals(Item? other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Character
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int Health { get; set; } = 100;


        public Character(string name, int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }

        public void PrintCharacter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + Name + " Age: " + Age + " Health: " + Health);
        }
    }

    internal class MainProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            // Create list
            List<Item> availableItems = new List<Item>();

            // Add items
            availableItems.Add(new Item(1, "Sword", 10));
            availableItems.Add(new Item(2, "Phonix Down", 10));
            availableItems.Add(new Item(3, "Potion", 100));
            availableItems.Add(new Item(4, "Cheese", 50));
            
            foreach (Item item in availableItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Id + " " + item.Name + " " + item.Effect);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Character tom = new Character("Tom", 23);
            tom.PrintCharacter();

            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to have (a reference to)  such a list in the Character class, and assign a reference or clone it. Or have a method `Character.Additem(Item)` that adds the given item to the Character's internal list (as opposed to exposing the list, which would be an obvious violation of the information hiding paradigm).

Comment: Also,  you'll probably want to actually implement that `Equatable<T>` interface.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you merely need to add a property to the character class as follows. (I took some liberties with the PrintCharacter method, but you can modify to your liking).

```
public class Character
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; } = 100;
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Character(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }      

    public void PrintCharacter()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {Name} \nAge: {Age} \nHealth: {Health}");
        Console.WriteLine("Items:");
        Items.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine($"\t{p.Name}, {p.Effect}"));                             
    }
}
```

Then in your main method you can simply assign the list of available items:

```
 foreach (Item item in availableItems)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(item.Id + " " + item.Name + " " + item.Effect);
      Console.WriteLine();
 }

 Character tom = new Character("Tom", 23);
 tom.Items = availableItems;
```

In the interest of time I didn't include the list of items as a parameter to the constructor, but you could certainly do that too, and it would arguably be a bit more elegant when it comes to creating your character in Main.

Comment: That was the perfect amount of info i needed. I just couldnt quite get the syntax right. I have just come over from Javascript and lists are a little tricky. haha i miss a good old array you pop and push. Thank you again

Comment: @TomBrockington You're quite welcome. Happy to help. Please consider officially accepting it if you feel it provides you with what you need.